# CSS/JS Clock: Strange positioning behaviour in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make an animated clock without using any images. I managed to get most of it right; however, when one of the hands reaches 12, it jumps all the way down to the bottom of the dial and then gradually moves upwards and reaches the correct position as it points to 3. This happens only in IE8. Any idea how to fix this?

This is the HTML file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39330021/Test/CSS3-JS-Clock-3.htm

Screenshot showing the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are using CSS3-rotations with IE8 matrix filters as fallback.
MS matrix filters work a bit different: The bounding-box of a rotated element gets expanded and takes more place than before the rotation. Because the bounding box's anchor point is top left, the image (or other content) moves down and right additionally to the correct transformation. You need to compensate for this movement by moving the box horizontally and vertically. Not that easy of a task.

**Static handling:**
There are a few recources on the internet helping you with **static** examples:

- [IETransformsTranslator](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/)
- [Correcting Transform Origin in IE](https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/correcting-transform-origin-and-translate-in-ie)

**Dynamic handling:**
For your dynamic purpose, if you really really really need to support IE8, I'd recommend GSAP, this is famous Greensock's library port from ActionScript 3 to JS. I know that it's compensating for transform origin and has a compatible solution for rotation in IE8:

<kbd>[**GSAP Animation Library**](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/)</kbd>

Comment: <blockquote>You need to compensate for this movement by moving the box horizontally and vertically.</blockquote>
<p>That is what I have been trying to do, but the code inside the condition `if((angle > 270) && (angle < 360))` never works. Funny things is that, if I use static rotation (by passing a number, say `312`, in place of `secondsHandAngle`), the element will be positioned correctly.</p>
<p>Thank you for the suggestions!</p>

Comment: You need to compensate for this alteration in size in EVERY angle (except 0, 90, 180 and 270° - there it's zero)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out myself. Whenever `angle` became `270`, IE made it `-90`. So I just added a line to add `360` to `angle` if it is less than `0`.